# Proper way to use Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This isn't a style question. Its more about the proper use of the language itself. I'm am fairly new to programming and I'm totally new to Objective-C and Cocoa but after reading about the language and looking through some sample code some usage patterns continue to pop up that do not make sense to me. Or rather they seem non optimal in my mind. I am hoping you all can help educate me in the proper uses of some of these language constructs.

interfaces vs protocols

I understand the concepts of interfaces and implementation as they relate to abstraction. However the dominant pattern I see in Objective-C sample code is the following...

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
  some ivars decls
}
some methods decls
@end
```

And then client code in the form of...

```
Foo* f = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

This seems odd to me. Foo seems to be an implementation in my mind (irregardless of the unfortunate naming of the @interface keyword). Interfaces in my mind do not expose instance variables. A client of this class should not be exposed to the details of my implementation.

Objective-C does have the @protocol keyword which in my mind is more of an interface than the @interface keyword. It allows you to define the methods and/or properties and that's it. No implementation. No instance variables. Just interface.

```
@protocol Foo <NSObject>
  some methods
  maybe some properties
@end

@interface FooProvider : NSObject
  + (FooProvider*) sharedProvider;
  - (id<Foo>) fooWithBlahBlah;
@end
```

So the client code would take the form of...

```
id<Foo> f = [[FooProvider sharedProvider] fooWithBlahBlah];
[f whatever];
```

This seems (at least to me) to be a more abstract usage of the language and isolates clients from implementation details they aught not to be dependent on. My question is which should I be striving to follow. I understand that there may be situations where one is preferable over the other but in general terms should one be the norm and one be the exception?

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can see where you are coming from in regards to the naming of the `@interface` keyword, but Objective-C uses the two keywords `@interface` and `@implementation` to differentiate between the class declaration (interface) and its definition (implementation). The `@interface` portion is usually placed in the class header file, and the `@implementation` portion goes in the source file. I agree with you 100% that the internal instance variables really shouldn't appear in the header file. I'm not sure what led to that decision, but my best guess is that it has to do with object inheritance. When you inherit from a parent class:

```
#import "ParentClass.h"
@interface MyClass : ParentClass
...
```

You also inherit all of the instance variables, which would be very difficult for the compiler to figure out unless those variables are declared in the class header.

You are also correct about the usage of `@protocol`, in that it essentially defines an interface that a class must adhere to. Protocols appear to be Objective-C's answer to multiple inheritance.

In my experience with Objective-C, protocols are not used very often. They have their place, but the majority of the code uses the basic `@interface` and `@implementation` keywords to define a class, and protocols are only used when some extra functionality is required that doesn't quite belong in the class hierarchy, but still needs to be shared across multiple classes.

If you're looking for guidance, I would say:

1. Accept the naming of the `@interface` and `@implementation` keywords, even if it doesn't quite jive with what you expect. When programming in Objective-C, drink the Kool-Aid and see those keywords the way the language designers intended.
2. Use protocols when they make sense in your code, but don't overuse them in an attempt to make Objective-C behave more like another language. It might work, but other people will cringe when they see your code, and it will make collaboration difficult.
3. Keep asking such good questions. You've brought up some very valid points!

Comment: Nice answer, especially for addressing the OP's question about private instance variables in the header file. Just adding a link to another SO question about that particular issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966893/why-are-instance-variables-defined-in-the-header-file-in-objective-c

Comment: Objective-C is a really thin layer over C.  It's really just managing a few symbol tables during the compile; very similar to the c preprocessor itself.  I'm sure most of the decisions were to make coding it easier (like using square braces instead of parens, they had to find something they could easily parse and extract from the surrounding code.  Probably the reason they chose to follow the Lisp syntax as well--easier to parse/extract/replace.  Neat hack though.  I think the header file is input only, not just a symbolic replace, so that's probably why they put variables there.

Comment: They were not following the Lisp syntax, but rather the Smalltalk syntax. Smalltalk tries to handle as much as possible (including conditional statements) through uniform use of message passing, and the syntax reflects this design principle by basically consisting of nested blocks.

Answer (score 12):

First, you need to understand that you're making a classic mistake: that the language you already know defines the terms used in all languages - as if a particular language has established a canonical nomenclature.

Java was begun in 1990 internally at Sun.  Objective-C had already been released in 1986.  So, if anything, Java's interface terminology is at odds with Objective-C, not the other way.  However, interface has a lot longer history as a term than either of these languages.

The idea behind the @interface in Objective-C is outlined in the [Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocGlossary.html):

> **interface**  Part of an Objective-C class specification that declares its public interface, which include its superclass name, instances variables, and public-method prototypes.

instance methods are class methods are public if they are declared in the interface.  if they are declared in the @implementation they are private.

The implementation goes into the @implementation.  Perhaps what is confusing you is that Java doesn't have the notion of a class declaration section like in Objective-C.  The class declaration declares the class interface in a generic way, without specifics of the implementation.  The @implementation has the *actual* implementation, which is the details of how the class @interface is implemented.

It's not wrong that objective-c is different than Java, it's just different.

But you're right, protocols are the closest analog to java interfaces in objective-c you're going to find.  It isn't a superclass for anything, and doesn't have any associated implementation.  You provide protocols much as you would interfaces in Java.

However, notice that protocols are not as common as classes in Objective-C.  That should help guide your thinking.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off as comparing Objective-C to Java. That wasn't my intent. The word Java never appeared in my original post. I was simply stating my internal conflict about what I consider to be an interface and what Objective-C considers to be an interface.

The advice of just do what the other code does doesn't exactly sit well with me internally but it does have some merit. When in rome etc... Gives me something to think about.

Comment: Well, your user of the term "interface" in the way Java uses it shows an understanding based on Java's terminology and concepts, but aren't necessarily valid outside of Java's conceptual framework.

Studying languages is a tremendously useful exercise - learn to appreciate the intellectual variances to inform your use of other languages.

Comment: (I didn't think the asker was directly pitting Obj-C against Java, but you're correct that there were some overtones that suggested confusion due use of terminology in the two languages.) Objective-C was actually invented in 1982, and I found it very interesting when I discovered that Objective-C had a non-trivial influence on Java — http://www.virtualschool.edu/objectivec/influenceOnJava.html

Answer (score 3):

No-one has yet explained why instance variables appear in the `@interface` of an Objective-C class. Objects are implemented as C structures which contain the instance variables. When you create a new subclass, a new type of structure is defined with all the superclass's ivars followed by the new class's ivars. The superclass structure must contain the ivars of *its* superclass, and then it's "turtles all the way down" to a structure which represents the ivars of the base class.

In the case of `NSObject` (and indeed `Object`), the base class structure only contains one ivar - a pointer called `isa` to the `Class` structure representing this object's class. So if I wanted to subclass it like this:

```
@interface GLObject : NSObject {
  int x;
}
@end
```

I need to know how to make a structure which looks like:

```
{
  Class isa;
  int x;
}
```

therefore the ivar layout of the parent class (and by induction *any* class) needs to be part of the class's public contract, i.e. part of its `@interface`. It may not be pretty, but there it is.

Comment: In point of fact, this is no longer true in the non-fragile runtime (64-bit Mac OS X and iPhone), which doesn’t use fixed layouts. When building for the non-fragile runtime, you can implicitly add ivars in the @implementation using the @synthesize directive. There is no technical reason not to allow a {} ivar block in the @implementation; word is that this was left out purely for reasons of time. Bugs have been filed.

Comment: Right, too true. There is no technical necessity since the @interface is used to inform the compiler of the necessary types and membership when compiling source which references the class without causing dependency on the implementation. If an ivar is @private, there is no real compelling reason for its existence in the @interface block other than syntax.

Comment: @both commenters: right. I thought introducing multiple runtimes at this point wasn't quite appropriate ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've also realized there is nothing really forcing my public facing interfaces to contain instance variables...

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
// some methods but no ivars
+ (Foo*) fooWithBlahBlah
@end
```

And the implementation file...

```
@implementation Foo

+ (Foo*) fooWithBlahBlah {
    return [[SomeDerivedFoo alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Where SomeDerivedFoo is declared internally not visible to clients...

```
@interface SomeDerivedFoo : Foo
{
    // instance vars
}
// overrides of methods
```

This would allow the component to expose an interface free of ivar dependencies. In fact this is the model that I see in so called "Class Clusters". This "feels" alot better to me.

My big problem with ivars in the public interface is all about dependency control. If my ivars are nothing but other Objective-C classes then yes I can get away with forward declarations but in the case of embedded C structs or other non class types I have to see the definition of those types and so my clients are now dependent on them.

Changing an instance variable should not cause clients of my interface to recompile. A relink is fine but not a recompile. In the case of a shared framework not even a relink should be necessary. This has nothing to do with any particular language. It has to do with isolation from details. That's a pretty universal goal in my mind.

This is what led to my original question about protocols vs interfaces. It seems that for a library or framework the more "correct" thing to do is to provide a set of protocols along with some sort of "Provider" or "Factory" classes to vend implementations of those protocols.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you're not able to support the 64-bit runtime and exclusively synthesise ivars, is to make an `id` ivar in your class. If you need to return to your class after shipping and add more instance variables, you can use this `id` as a container for them.

This allows you to write less complex code, while giving you some leeway to change things behind your client's backs without forcing a recompile.

By typing the ivar as `id` you're not promising anything to client code (an it should be made `@private` anyway).

I would imagine having all your public classes act as proxies to private implementations would get a little unmanageable. Keep in mind, if you do, you can use runtime forwarding to reduce the amount of code you have to write in the public class. See `-[NSObject forwardingTargetForSelector:]`. It's documented  in the [10.5 Foundation Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/ReleaseNotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html)